# CsvReader Mapping and Conversion : No coercion operator

Tags: c#, csvhelper

First, thank you for your time. I'm trying to use the CsvHelper for the first time along with a custom class and custom map. I'm getting "No cercion operator is defined between types 'System.Int32' and 'System.String'"

Here are my classes:

```
class Vendor
{
    public string VENDORID { get; set; }
    public string VENDORNAME { get; set; }
    public string VENDORSHORTNAME { get; set; }
    public string VENDORCHECKNAME { get; set; }
    public string HOLD { get; set; }
    public string VENDORSTATUS { get; set; }
    public string VENDORCLASSID { get; set; }
    public string PRIMARYVENDORADDRESSID { get; set; }
    public string VENDORCONTACT { get; set; }
    public string ADDRESS1 { get; set; }
    public string ADDRESS2 { get; set; }
    public string ADDRESS3 { get; set; }
    public string CITY { get; set; }
    public string STATE { get; set; }
    public string ZIPCODE { get; set; }
    public string COUNTRYCODE { get; set; }
    public string COUNTRY { get; set; }
    public string PHONE1 { get; set; }
    public string PHONE2 { get; set; }
    public string PHONE3 { get; set; }
    public string FAXNUMBER { get; set; }
    public string VENDORACCOUNTNUMBER { get; set; }
    public string PAYMENTTERMSID { get; set; }
    public string TAXIDNUMBER { get; set; }
    public string TAXREGISTRATIONNUMBER { get; set; }
    public string USER_DEFINED1 { get; set; }
    public string USER_DEFINED2 { get; set; }
    public string TAX1099TYPE { get; set; }
    public string TAX1099BOXNUMBER { get; set; }
    public string PURCHASESACCOUNT { get; set; }
    public string TRANSITROUTINGNUMBER { get; set; }
    public string EFTBANKACCOUNTNUMBER { get; set; }
}

class VendorMap : CsvClassMap<Vendor>
{
    public override void CreateMap()
    {
        Map(m => m.VENDORID).Name("Vendor ID");
        Map(m => m.VENDORNAME).Name("Vendor name");
        Map(m => m.VENDORSHORTNAME).Name("Vendor short name");
        Map(m => m.VENDORCHECKNAME).Name("Vendor check name");
        Map(m => m.HOLD).Name("Hold").Default(1);
        Map(m => m.VENDORSTATUS).Name("Vendor status").Default("Active");
        Map(m => m.VENDORCLASSID).Name("Vendor class ID");
        Map(m => m.PRIMARYVENDORADDRESSID).Name("Primary vendor address ID");
        Map(m => m.VENDORCONTACT).Name("Vendor contact");
        Map(m => m.ADDRESS1).Name("Address 1");
        Map(m => m.ADDRESS2).Name("Address 2");
        Map(m => m.ADDRESS3).Name("Address 3");
        Map(m => m.CITY).Name("City");
        Map(m => m.STATE).Name("State");
        Map(m => m.ZIPCODE).Name("Zip Code");
        Map(m => m.COUNTRYCODE).Name("Country code");
        Map(m => m.COUNTRY).Name("Country");
        Map(m => m.PHONE1).Name("Phone 1");
        Map(m => m.PHONE2).Name("Phone 2");
        Map(m => m.PHONE3).Name("Phone 3");
        Map(m => m.FAXNUMBER).Name("Fax number");
        Map(m => m.VENDORACCOUNTNUMBER).Name("Vendor account number");
        Map(m => m.PAYMENTTERMSID).Name("Payment terms ID");
        Map(m => m.TAXIDNUMBER).Name("Tax ID number");
        Map(m => m.TAXREGISTRATIONNUMBER).Name("Tax registration number");
        Map(m => m.USER_DEFINED1).Name("User-defined 1");
        Map(m => m.USER_DEFINED2).Name("User-defined 2");
        Map(m => m.TAX1099TYPE).Name("Tax 1099 type:");
        Map(m => m.TAX1099BOXNUMBER).Name("Tax 1099 box number");
        Map(m => m.PURCHASESACCOUNT).Name("Purchases account");
        Map(m => m.TRANSITROUTINGNUMBER).Name("Transit Routing Number");
        Map(m => m.EFTBANKACCOUNTNUMBER).Name("EFT Bank Account Number");
    }
}
```

Here is where I am reading a file:

```
CsvReader csv = new CsvReader(reader);

csv.Configuration.HasHeaderRecord = true;
csv.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<VendorMap>();

List<Vendor> vendors = null;

try
{
    vendors = csv.GetRecords<Vendor>().ToList();
```

Ideally, I would like the HOLD, TAX99TYPE, and TAX99BOXNUMBER properties types to be "short". However, with that I received the error "The conversion cannot be performed".

Here is part of my test CSV:

```
"Vendor ID","Vendor name","Vendor short name","Vendor check name","Hold","Vendor status","Vendor clas
"AA0011","UAT Demo","","","","Active","","Residence","Demo UAT","TESTING","TESTING","","TESTING","KS"
"AA0011","UAT Demo","","","","Active","","Supply","Demo UAT","NEW ADDRESS","NEW ADDRESS","","NEW ADDR
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is essentially caused by mismatch of the types between column definition (string):

```
public string HOLD { get; set; }
```

and it's default value (Int32),

```
Map(m => m.HOLD).Name("Hold").Default(1);
```

As far as I'm aware, with the current version of CsvHelper, the default value type should match the type definition of its corresponding column.

You have two options . Either define column HOLD as `short`, or change the default value to be a string (ie `"1"`).

Assuming you've already tried the former option, the error "The conversion cannot be performed" probably means that one or more column values in your CSV file
contains a value which cannot be converted to a `short` (ie an alphanumeric value).

Comment: I ended up changing the default value to "1" and then converting the field when later used in code. I am still hoping to grasp a better understanding of the type conversion and how to implement a custom conversion as is described by the CsvHelper documentation which I simply fail to grasp properly at this juncture. http://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/